# How do I use the NEST client to configure Elasticsearch to use AutoMap types as the default template for dynamically mapped objects?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm adding objects to an index dynamically, so they're all indexed using the _default_ mapping. This is problematic because it leads to things like a `Guid` being mapped as `text` fields rather than as a `keyword`. The [AutoMap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html) function provided by the NEST client "automagically infers the correct" field from any given datatype, but it does so only when called explicitly. Is there any way to force the _default_ mapping to use the same template as the AutoMap function? Or do I need to add some additional code which loops through all of my possible object types and creates an `IndexDescriptor` for each one preemptively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to apply a mapping to a newly created template

```
var putIndexTemplateResponse = client.PutIndexTemplate("default", t => t
    .Template("*")
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map("_default_", tm => tm
            .Properties(p => p
                .Keyword(k => k
                    .Name("id")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This will map the `id` property for any type in any newly created index as a keyword field.

If you need something more convention based, you can use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) with rules to determine how dynamically added fields should be mapped

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("index-name", t => t
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map("_default_", tm => tm
            .DynamicTemplates(d => d
                .DynamicTemplate("default", dt => dt
                    .Match("id")
                    .MatchMappingType("string")
                    .Mapping(mm => mm
                        .Keyword(k => k)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Both approaches set mapping conventions within Elasticsearch. If you intend to determine any conventions within your own code e.g. [using the visitor pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html), you'll need to explicitly tell Elasticsearch about the resulting mapping.

Comment: Presumably I could tailor the `.Match("id")` line to match something like `RemoteId` by telling it to match on `.Match("*Id")` or something similar?

Comment: @Necoras yes, you can