# ElasticSearch - Nest - creating a template

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am using `ElasticSearch` version `6.4.1` and I am using it from my `C#` application using `Nest` library version `6.1.0`.

I an trying to create an `Index Template` using `Nest` without success.

The only documentation I found if this old documentation: [Nest Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/templates.html)

I can't find any documentation for the newer versions.

I did notice they have a method named `PutIndexTemplate` for the `ElasticClient` but again I can't find any documentation or examples on how to use it

I have seen this post: [nst template example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442043/how-do-i-use-the-nest-client-to-configure-elasticsearch-to-use-automap-types-as) but looks like its broken as I get an compilation error on `.Template`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the way it's done:

```
var putIndexTemplateResponse = m_ElasticClient.PutIndexTemplate("server_alerts", t => t
    .IndexPatterns("server_alerts*")
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map("alert", tm => tm
            .Properties(p => p
                .Keyword(k => k
                    .Name("id")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```